# Conversion of Matlab loop to Python loop

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix

I am trying to convert the following Matlab code to Python :

```matlab
for j=1:n
    for i=1:m
        a1(i,j) = sum(-4*f*d(i))*log(NormPS{i,j}(f1:f2)));
    end
end
```

where n=55 and m=103; f has a 1 by 441 dimension matrix (consider any random values)
f1=10 and f2=450 and `log(NormPS{i,j}(f1:f2)))` gives a matrix of 441 by 1 dimension and `d` is a 1 by 103 dimension matrix.

This is what I tried in Python:

```py
for j in range(np.int64(n)):
    for i in range(np.int64(m)): 
        a= -np.mat(4)*np.mat(f)*np.mat(d[:i])
        b=np.log((NormPS[i,j] [(d).astype(int)]).reshape(-1,1))
        #check=(d[:i])
```

I am getting the same result for the log part of the Matlab which is b in my python code. However, for the sum part I am getting this error`error : shapes (1,441) and (0,103) not aligned: 441 (dim 1) != 0 (dim 0)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File ~\Desktop\spyder_files\2D_spyder_file\algebra_2D_spyder.py:48 in <module> a= -np.mat(4)*np.mat(f)*np.mat(d[:i])
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py:218 in mul return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
File <__array_function__ internals>:5 in dot ValueError: shapes (1,441) and (0,103) not aligned: 441 (dim 1) != 0 (dim 0)
```

Is there any way I can rewrite `a=sum(-4*f*d(i))`? I am sure the error is in `d(i)`.

Comment: Please provide the entire stacktrace in your question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Desktop\spyder_files\2D_spyder_file\algebra_2D_spyder.py:48 in <module>
    a= -np.mat(4)*np.mat(f)*np.mat(d[:i])

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py:218 in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))

  File <__array_function__ internals>:5 in dot

ValueError: shapes (1,441) and (0,103) not aligned: 441 (dim 1) != 0 (dim 0)

Comment: @ michael ruth is that what you were asking for ?

Comment: In the Matlab code you were using `d(i)` ... but in Python you are using `d[:i]`.  These are not the same.   `d[:i]` will give you a slice from the beginning of the array/list through the index `i`.   I don't think that is what you want.  Also, Numpy does not recommend using `np.mat` anymore

Answer (score 0):

First, Numpy has recommend to no [longer use the Matrix class.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy.matrix).

Also, you are using `d(i)` in Matlab and `d[:i]` in Python.  These are not equivalent. Matlab's `d(i)` will return a single element from the array `d`.  `d[:i]` is a slice from the index 0 through index i.
Example:

```
d = np.array([1,2,3,4])
i = 2
print(d[:i])
[1, 2]

print(d[i])
3
```

I think what you are looking for if the dimensions of `f` and `d` are as you say something like this:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.random.rand(1,441)
d = np.random.rand(1,103)

#Set i just for the example:
i = 1
a= -4*f*d[0,i]
print(f'The Shape of "a" is: {a.shape}')
```

Returns:

```
The Shape of "a" is: (1, 441)
```

However, based on the error message you included it looks like `d` is really a `(0,103)` ... if that is the case then change `d[0,i]` to just `d[i]` in the above code and it should work.